# Text bleeding out of page in knitr using latex

Tags: latex, knitr, sweave, xtable, rnw

I am using the following code snippet to write some text data frame as a table.

```
temp<-c("A white paper is a document that describes a given problem and proposes a specific solution to the problem.", "Originally used to describe government policy, white papers are most common today in corporate settings.", "A typical white paper might list ways to meet a client's marketing needs, suggest the use of a certain product for a technical process, or identify ways to streamline internal communication.")
myTable<-as.data.frame(temp)

myTable<-print.xtable(xtable(textData,caption="Some Text Data"),caption.placement="top",print.results="F", tabular.environment="tabularx", width="\\textwidth")
```

The table border is limited to the page, but the text still bleeds out. How do I get the text to come within the table limits?

Comment: Can you make a reproducible and complete example including some simple example data that demonstrates this?

Comment: I made changes to my question.